# How can I plot training accuracy, training loss with respect to epochs in TensorFlow version v1.x in given program

Tags: python, tensorflow, plot, graph, loss

i am new to tensorflow programming. I want to plot training accuracy, training loss, validation accuracy and validation loss in following program.I am using tensorflow version 1.x in google colab.The code snippet is as follows.

```
# hyperparameters
n_neurons = 128  
learning_rate = 0.001  
batch_size = 128
n_epochs = 5
# parameters
n_steps = 32   
n_inputs = 32  
n_outputs = 10   
# build a rnn model
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])  
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])  
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)  
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)  
logits = tf.layers.dense(state, n_outputs)  
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)  
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)  
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)  
prediction = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)  
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(prediction, tf.float32))  
# input data
x_test = x_test.reshape([-1, n_steps, n_inputs]) 
# initialize the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# train the model
with tf.Session() as sess:    sess.run(init)  
    n_batches = 100  
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):  
        for batch in range(n_batches):  
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x_train, y: y_train})  
            loss_train, acc_train = sess.run([loss, accuracy], feed_dict={X: 
            x_train, y: y_train})  
            print('Epoch: {}, Train Loss: {:.3f}, Train Acc: 
            {:.3f}'.format(epoch + 1, loss_train, acc_train))  
            loss_test, acc_test = sess.run([loss, accuracy], feed_dict={X: 
            x_test, y: y_test})  
            print('Test Loss: {:.3f}, Test Acc: {:.3f}'.format(loss_test, 
            acc_test))
```

Comment: Hi Rajpal, Please surround your code with ``` such that it is identified as code. It would also be helpful to describe what your current code is producing and why you are not satisfied with that output.

Answer (score 8):

As Viviann commented, please use ``` when putting code because it is hard to understand it.
But the following code can be helpful:

*Side note: This is using keras

```
acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
```

Here you assign the values from the training and validation (for accuracy and loss). I believe you have done that part already.

The following part is for plotting those values

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)

plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'bo', label='Training acc')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation acc')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()

plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'bo', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

It should give you something like these:

[image: Example of plot values(training, validation acc and loss]

Comment: Just a side note. If you train the model and then decide to train for more epochs the history object is not preserved and will only contain data for the second training session. So if you want the full set of data you need to save the data from the first training session then append the new data to it.

Comment: That is a good point. Did not see the point on adding it, since the person asking the question didnt not specify it.

Comment: Thanks for kind response. After running the code , I got AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'history'. This may be because I am not using fit() for training. Please guide me.

Comment: I am posting the complete code. kindly do the needful.