# Plotting training and validation accuracy and loss in Tensor flow 1.x version

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there anyway to plot the training and validation accuracy and loss in Tensor flow 1.x version?
As, in tensor flow 2.x, this can be done using this below code snippets. But, it doesnot work in tensor flow 1.x version.

```
loss_train = history.history['train_loss']
loss_val = history.history['val_loss']
epochs = range(1,35)
plt.plot(epochs, loss_train, 'g', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, loss_val, 'b', label='validation loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this similar to your problem: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483337/how-can-i-plot-training-accuracy-training-loss-with-respect-to-epochs-in-tensor)

Comment: @Gautam-Chettiar, this solution present in the link, only works for tensorflow 2.x.