# Save trained weights in machine learning code

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, transformer-model

i have colab for running machine learning model but when it gets 80 epoch my colab ram crashes and i can not go beind the 80 epochs.i want to somebody to help me save the trained weights somewhere and after the ram crashes i start training the model from that epoch.This is my code, how can i write that purpose code in this python code and where?

```
for comm_round in range(comms_round):

    global_weights = global_model.get_weights()

    scaled_local_weight_list = list()

    client_names= list(clients_batched.keys())
    random.shuffle(client_names)

    for client in client_names:
        local_model = Transformer
        local_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001),
                            metrics='acc')

        local_model.set_weights(global_weights)

        local_model.fit(clients_batched[client], epochs=1, verbose=0, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])

        scaling_factor = weight_scalling_factor(clients_batched, client)
        scaled_weights = scale_model_weights(local_model.get_weights(), scaling_factor)
        scaled_local_weight_list.append(scaled_weights)

        K.clear_session()

    average_weights = sum_scaled_weights(scaled_local_weight_list)

    global_model.set_weights(average_weights)

    for(X_test, Y_test) in test_batched:
        global_acc, global_loss = test_model(test_x, test_y, global_model, comm_round + 1)
```

this code is for final step and for federated learning.

Comment: Why both `keras` and `torch` tags? Please keep only the tag of the framework you are actually working with, and do not use irrelevant ones.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @desertnaut, in your case removing the `torch` tag would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Potential Solution

---

> **Note**: I have seen that you have `checkpoint_callback` inside your `fit` function which I presume might be a model callback? If so not sure if this would work but it is the general approach that comes to my mind when trying to save off the optimum weights during training when using TensorFlow framework. Since this process is continuous across epochs even if it fails during a late epoch I guess the best runs prior should have been saved off.

You can use TensorFlow's `ModelCheckpoint` callback to automatically save your model's weights after each epoch. You can then load these weights to resume training if your runtime crashes. Here's how to set it up:

1. Define the `ModelCheckpoint` callback before your training loop:

```py
checkpoint_filepath = '/path/to/checkpoint/directory'
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_loss',  # change this to what you want to monitor
    mode='auto', 
    save_best_only=False,
    verbose=1,
)
```

2. Include the `ModelCheckpoint` callback in your `fit` function:

```py
for comm_round in range(comms_round):
    # ... existing code ...

    for client in client_names:
        # ... existing code ...

        local_model.fit(clients_batched[client], epochs=1, verbose=0, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])

        # ... existing code ...
```

After each epoch, the model's weights are saved to the specified filepath.

3. If your runtime crashes and you need to resume training, you can load the saved weights into your model:

```py
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

Please note that the path to the directory where you want to save the model weights needs to exist. If you are using Google Colab, it might be a good idea to save your weights in your Google Drive. This way, the saved weights will persist even if the Colab runtime is recycled. To do this, you will need to mount your Google Drive to the Colab notebook.

Also, please note that this will not automatically save the current communication round. You would need to manage this manually. For example, you can save the current communication round number to a file each time you save your model weights. When you resume training, you can read this number from the file and continue the communication rounds from there.

Comment: Thank you for you response.I have another problem, I am using Acc in my code to test the model.I need another methods to test my model including F1score, Recall, Precision, confusion matrix.Is tehre any way to have these test metrics from Accuracy that I used in my model for test  or I have to run every code again?I wonder if I could ask you to help me in this case. Thanks

Comment: Sure, firstly would you be able to upvote my answer if it was useful and perhaps tick it if it solves your initial problem? Secondly this is a separate question so I recommend creating a new post to provide more details on what the problem is (**I find it hard to understand**). Having said that if you want to track more metrics you should be able to provide them as a list to the `metrics` parameter inside compile? ie `local_model.compile(..., metrics=['acc', <other metrics>])`. You can find a detailed list of them on TensorFlows site: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics

Comment: Thanks bro. I appreciate it. I want also to plot the accuracy and loss because i need to put thes visualized plots in my ISI.I would be very thankful to help to solve this.I have the code but I dont get any data in plot.I dont know whre i put the code to have this plots.I use federated learning so we have local model and global; model and the accuracy of the global mode is needed.

Comment: No problem! I appreciate you accepting the answer **_but_** if you could upvote it too that would be great. To plot your training/validation metrics data you'll want to make use of the `History` object that is returned from your model once you call the `fit` method i.e having a line like `history = local_model.fit(...)` in your code and then following the guidance from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483337/how-can-i-plot-training-accuracy-training-loss-with-respect-to-epochs-in-tensor